# In App Purchases don't work during Apple review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In App Purchases work in Sandbox environment but don't work during Apple review which results in the app rejection:

[image]

I can't find the problem as In App purchases work well on the test device with Sandbox accounts. I did send the IAPs for review as well and I don't do any kind of receipt validation.

Any ideas where I can find the problem roots?

Answer (score 2):

Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store.

The 21007 status code indicates that this receipt is a sandbox receipt, but it was sent to the production service for verification. A status of 0 indicates that the receipt was properly verified.

Look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-RECEIPTURL

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

**How do I verify my receipt (iOS)?**

Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Add some sort of logging that you can see remotely. I suspect they're hitting one of the SKErrorDomain errors because of the weird environment they operate in (app store signed builds, but sandbox accounts).

Do you refresh the receipt in your purchase flow? That's a step where they typically encounter an error.

Comment: Good idea. I use SwiftyStoreKit library but I don't use any receipt validation though.