# In App Purchase working fine in testing mode but not working in app review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I integrated in app purchase in my app and i tested it with created test account. It was working fine but when i submitted it to app store for live in app review my app got rejected due to:

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code “Sandbox receipt used in production,” you should validate against the test environment instead.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you validating the receipt on your server?  Is the alert produced by your code? Under what conditions does it display that alert?

Answer (score 1):

From [WWDC 2013 Session 308](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/308/) at 44:00:

> "The app reviewers are actually testing your production signed, ready-to-go-into-the-store binary, but against the test environment. So your production signed app will see test environment receipts".

What this means is that if you're using a server to validate your receipt, make sure to validate the receipt against the production server first, and if that validation fails, then validate the receipt against the sandbox server.

This is what is instructed to do in the rejection reason you received:

> "The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. **If validation fails with the error code “Sandbox receipt used in production,” you should validate against the test environment instead**."

Please also see the following answers to similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398571/5948155
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21515982/5948155

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Actually I am using this function to purchase:

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am using this function to purchase:

```
func purchase(_ purchase: RegisteredPurchase) {
    self.view.showLoad()
   // NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleId + "." + purchase.rawValue, atomically: true) { result in
     //   NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationFinished()
      self.view.hideLoad()
        print(result)
        if case .success(let purchase) = result {

           self.refrenceNumber = purchase.transaction.transactionIdentifier!
         //   print(purchase.transaction.transactionDate)
            self.sendRefrence()
            if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
            }
        }else{
            if let alert = self.alertForPurchaseResult(result) {
            self.showAlert(alert)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It working fine in testing environment but in review its response is :
**paymentInvalid**

How can i change environment for purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I understand the issue, but when I am purchasing in app purchase product. I am not validating receipt. I am direct purchasing and after calling purchase function as i updated above it gives error **.paymentinvalid**.  where i have to validate or change or where i have to give sandbox or production url to purchase or check. Because my function is not checking any thing directly gives error.

Comment: did you find the solution ?