# iOS In-App Purchase fails production only

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an In-App that fails consistently in production while it works perfectly on testflight.

In the console I see the following errors from the `itunesstored` process:

```
ISBiometricStore: [PSD2] Failed to load URL bag ISBiometricStore:
[AutoEnrollment] Failed to load URL bag 
DeviceScorer: Failed to find bag
```

The iap is cleared to sale and is approved in app store connect. How do I resolve this issue or get more information on the the cause of the error?

Comment: Does your server able to verify in-app purchase receipt in test mode?
Check this, might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21515982/12688502 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398571/12688502

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in case it helps anyone. There was a pending iOS update on the iPhone.. after installing it, it worked well. I realised it when I tried installing it on an iPad.

Comment: So it's a kind of OS bug.

Comment: feels like it. It happened again weeks later, and a restart fixed it. Maybe it's a because I keep alternating between multiple versions (Sandbox, dev, prod, testflight) and it messes up. I will need to test this on multiple devices to make sure.